# Ubuntu fails to boot after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, 18.04, fstab, do-release-upgrade

I had a working Ubuntu 16.04 installation with FDE encryption via luks. Followed the process below.

1. Upgraded using the sudo do-release-upgrade command.
2. Most programs continued to work after upgrade.
3. Proceeded to reboot.
4. I get to the decryption screen, accepts my passphrase and then freezes.
5. I can access emergency shell via F2.

I thought from some googling it was potentially to do with my fstab entries, and replaced the commented out lines with their UUID equivilant (I think...) but I'm not sure. I could be on the wrong track.

I've included several outputs below.

**/etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=3a072453-c27f-4ee5-9766-5061d561414b / ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e92bbca1-13cb-4703-96fa-d952dbcd66c9 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
#/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=5d17625c-275d-4661-9cb9-6fe00f22f3a4 none  swap    sw      0   0
```

**/etc/crypttab**

```
sda5_crypt UUID=3a072453-c27f-4ee5-9766-5061d561414b none luks, discard
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="j3TH71-puaI-ynT5-PNQE-41KE-7lv1-Ve0Tnm" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root: UUID="79d14c2e-5e38-4a2f-b5cd-b168759becd8" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="e92bbca1-13cb-4703-96fa-d952dbcd66c9" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="7a9973ba-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="3a072453-c27f-4ee5-9766-5061d561414b" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="7a9973ba-05"
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="5d17625c-275d-4661-9cb9-6fe00f22f3a4" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="HFS" PARTUUID="4613ee39-4727-4347-8134-173f590f716f"
/dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4fa17ecb-7fe2-4fbe-bf71-494e61a55df4"
```

**Excerpt from journalctl -ab**

```
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 28 08:20:54 gold systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 316 (plymouthd).
Mar 28 08:21:43 gold kernel: usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device/start timed out.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/e92bbca1-13cb-4703-96fa-d952dbcd66c9.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
-- Subject: Unit boot.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit boot.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: boot.mount: Job boot.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e92bbca1\x2d13cb\x2d4703\x2d96fa\x2dd952dbcd66c9.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device/start timed out.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for sda5_crypt.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-cryptsetup@sda5_crypt.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-cryptsetup@sda5_crypt.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dev-mapper-sda5_crypt.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-mapper-sda5_crypt.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dev-mapper-sda5_crypt.device has failed.
-- 
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-mapper-sda5_crypt.device: Job dev-mapper-sda5_crypt.device/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Encrypted Volumes.
-- Subject: Unit cryptsetup.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit cryptsetup.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: cryptsetup.target: Job cryptsetup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@sda5_crypt.service: Job systemd-cryptsetup@sda5_crypt.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3a072453\x2dc27f\x2d4ee5\x2d9766\x2d5061d561414b.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device/start timed out.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/5d17625c-275d-4661-9cb9-6fe00f22f3a4.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.swap has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.swap has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
-- Subject: Unit swap.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit swap.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5d17625c\x2d275d\x2d4661\x2d9cb9\x2d6fe00f22f3a4.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 28 08:22:22 gold systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

Thanks in advance